# How to connect a Wi-Fi AP to an 802.1X-protected Ethernet LAN?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, peap

To connect my laptop to my organization's Ethernet LAN, I have to enable IEEE 802.1X PEAP authentication, and set the authentication method to Secure Password (MSCHAP v2), which requires no client-side certificate. I then have to set the authentication mode to user authentication, and enter a user name and password. Then it connects to the internet.

How can I set up a standard D-Link Wi-Fi router to connect to that kind of 802.1X-protected Ethernet and share it wirelessly? I tried with PPPoE but it doesn't work.

Would OpenWrt help?